# TensorFlow RNN training 100% CPU while only using 60% GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, deep-learning

I'm working on code that trains a relatively large RNN (128 cell LSTM and some added layers). The main process is maxing out a core on the CPU, and I'm wondering if this is normal or whether I can optimize it. During the training loop (session.run calls) it's using about 60-70% GPU load while using 100% CPU load on one core. Note that data sampling work is already being done concurrently on other cores, so it's just the updating of the model parameters. Is this regular for such applications in TensorFlow or should the CPU load be much lower, while using the full capacity of the GPU?

Comment: Interesting... I'm doing some training which is only using 30% CPU and 25% CPU and looking for answers on why it doesn't saturate either of the two.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have full documentation on it yet, but you can take a look at the profiling information to see if it gives you more of an idea of where the time is going:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659

Answer (score 0):

I think RNN cell have two input, it must wait for those two direction input when traning data, in other word, it optimize parallelism don't as easy as CNN. You can use a big batch size to improve the GPU utilization rate, but maybe cause other problem like that paper ***On Large-Batch Training for Deep Learning: Generalization Gap and Sharp Minima***.